# How do I erase printed characters in a console application(Linux)?

Tags: linux, console, character, erase

I am creating a small console app that needs a progress bar. Something like...

```
Conversion: 175/348 Seconds   |==========          |  50%
```

My question is, how do you erase characters already printed to the console? When I reach the 51st percentage, I have to erase this line from the console and insert a new line. In my current solution, this is what happens...

```
Conversion: 175/348 Seconds   |==========          |  50%
Conversion: 179/348 Seconds   |==========          |  52%
Conversion: 183/348 Seconds   |==========          |  54%
Conversion: 187/348 Seconds   |===========         |  56%
```

Code I use is...

```
print "Conversion: $converted_seconds/$total_time Seconds   $progress_bar  $converted_percentage%\n";
```

I am doing this in Linux using PHP(only I will use the app - so please excuse the language choice). So, the solution should work on the Linux platform - but if you have a solution that's cross platform, that would be preferable.

Comment: I hope this example helps you
[php example - remove lines in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72021076/9234535)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think you need to apologize for the language choice. PHP is a great language for console applications.

Try this out:

```
<?php
for( $i=0;$i<10;$i++){
  print "$i \r";
  sleep(1);
}
?>
```

The "\r" will overwrite the line with the new text. To make a new line you can just use "\n", but I'm guessing you already knew that.

Hope this helps! I know this works in Linux, but I don't know if it works in Windows or other operating systems.

Comment: Also, many dumb terminals (or terminal emulators, or brain dead frame buffer modes) will be confused by this, as will various SSH clients. A literal backspace '\b' is the safest way to go.

Comment: I totally forget you could do this on the shell.

Comment: Wow! I am going to try this. Will add some colors to see if it works

Comment: @GnomeCubed PHP should not be used ever.

Answer (score 9):

To erase a previously printed character you have three options:

- `echo chr(8) . " ";` echoes the back character, and will move the cursor back one place, and the space then overwrites the character. You can use `chr(8)` multiple times in a row to move back multiple characters.
- `echo "\r";` will return the cursor to the start of the current line. You can now replace the line with new text.
- The third option is to set the line and column of the cursor position using ANSI escape codes, then print the replacement characters. It might not work with all terminals:

```
  function movecursor($line, $column){
      echo "\033[{$line};{$column}H";
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

\r did the trick.

For future reference, \b does not work in PHP in Linux. I was curious - so I did a couple of experiments in other languages as well(I did this in Linux - I don't know if the result will be the same in Windows/Mac)..

\b Works in...

- Perl
- Ruby
- Tcl - with code `puts -nonewline "Hello\b"`

\b Doesn't work in

- PHP - the code `print "Hello\b";` prints out `Hello\b`
- Python  - code `print "Hello\b"` prints out `Hello<new line>` . Same result with `print "Hello\b",`

Comment: python print appends \n automatically. use sys.stdout.wirte instead of print if you want to stay on the same line

Comment: The backspace character still exists, of course! It just isn't available in string literals with an escape. Try `chr(8)`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's the same in Linux but in Windows console apps you can print \r and the cursor will return to the first left position of the line allowing you to overwrite all the characters to the right.

You can use \b to move back a single character but since you're going to be updating your progress bar \r would be simpler to use than printing \b x number of times.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be pretty old topic but I will drop my 5 into.

```
for ($i; $i<_POSITION_; $i--) {
   echo "\010"; //issue backspace 
}
```

Found this on the internet some time ago, unfortunately don't remember where. So all credits goes to original author.

Answer (score 0):

to erase a previously printed character, I print a backspace after it:
print "a"
print "\b"

will print *nothing* (actually it will print and then a backspace, but you probably won't notice it)