# Refreshing values in the console

Tags: c#, c, console

I don't know how to explain this very well, but here's a shot at it. Don't hesitate to ask for clarification, please.

Suppose I have a console that displays numbers that change with certain events. The best example would be a "plane" instrument that shows altitude, direction, wind, etc. Like so:

```
Altitude: 9876ft      Direction: NE
Wind:     5km, NE
...
```

I only have a Windows and Linux console and I want these values to refresh themselves **in place**.

Is this simple? C or C# code and any pointers would definitely help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The curses library is the usual way to handle this, and it is reasonably portable.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Console.SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx) method for this purpose.

Comment: The question mentions the Linux console, which this isn't going to be too helpful for.

Comment: This method exists in Mono Class Library, so I assume it will work on Linux too.

Answer (score 1):

you can always use something like

```
for(;;)
{
  printf("value: %d", something);
  update_value();
#ifdef WINDOWS
  system("cls");
#else
  system("clear");
#endif
}
```

but it's the dirtiest way to do it =)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [ANSI code sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to erase the console and write over again.

If you just want to update one line, in UNIX you can use the the `\r` control character to go to the beginning of the line without going to the next one. Any further writing will override what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430713/how-do-i-erase-printed-characters-in-a-console-applicationlinux). I think the solutions provided there would fit your needs.