# How to update a output field in terminal without output a new line?

Tags: c++, shell, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update a printed message in terminal without reprinting (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337529/how-to-update-a-printed-message-in-terminal-without-reprinting-linux)

I have c++ code, performing some simulations.

I want to show the percentage of my simulation, but I don't want to output a new line every step, like

%1

%2

%3

...

Is there a way, in c++ or in shell scripts to show the progress without creating new lines?

Thanks

### Edit 1

Anyone know how to update a number on my personal webpage without refreshing the whole page?

Thanks

### Edit 2

```
double N=0;
forAll (internalIDs_, i) {
    N++;
    double percent = 100*N/internalIDs_.size();
    // Info<< "\rProgress: " << percent << "%" << endl;
    printf("\r[%6.4f%%]",percent);}
```

The terminal cursor keeps blinking cyclically through the numbers, very annoything, how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The trick used for this is to return to the first position in the current line instead of progressing to the next line.

This is done by writing the `\r` character (carriage return) to the terminal/stdout.

Comment: Hmm, so I need to `fflush(stdout);`?

Comment: Yes. Flushing is part of std::endl. As you don't use std::endl, you need to flush. In C++ you can flush with std::cout.flush(), or use std::cout << "\rtest" << std::flush; Caution: Flushing too often can severely degrade the performance of your application. E.g. if you output percentages, only update your output when the number is actually increased.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I see the terminal cursor keeps blinking through the percentage numbers in a very fast way and cyclicly, what should I do to get rid of this..

Comment: As I said, less updates help. But it is hard to get rid of the cursor. It's a completely new topic.

Comment: @ypnos How would I do this for multiple lines? Let's say I'd like to update values across 6 lines - 1 on each line.

Comment: @DJSquared There is no simple solution for this. You can put the terminal in a different mode to do things like a console UI etc., but it is more complicated. A popular library for this is `ncurses`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Answer (score 18):

```
cout << "\r%1";
cout << "\r%2";
cout << "\r%3";
```

...

\r - move at the begin of line;

but!
if :

```
cout << "\rsomelongmessage";
cout << "\rshort";
```

then you get at out:

```
shortongmessage
```

because of:

```
somelongmessage
^^^^^
short
```

but you can:

```
cout << "\rsomelongmessage";
cout << "\rshort          ";
```

then you get finally:

```
short
```