# Progressbar C++

Tags: c++, return, progress-bar, cout

I'm trying to make a progressbar for my program that's running on a unix server. It's at the end of a large for loop and looks like this:

```
struct CodeBook{
    string Residue;
    vector<string> CodeWords;
};

    int r = 0, d = 2;
    string code;

    vector<CodeBook> CodeBooks(Weight(n+1, 4, d));

    for (r = 0; r < Weight(n+1, 4, d); r++){
            do{
                    getline(Input, code);
                    if (code[0] == 'R') CodeBooks[r].Residue = code;
                    else if (isdigit(code[0]))CodeBooks[r].CodeWords.push_back(code);
            } while (code != ""); //if the line is empty, end the loop and move to the next

            if (r%256==0) {fflush(stdout); cout << (r / Weight(n+1, 4, d)) << "\r";} //the problem
    }
```

All it does is print a never-changing 0 at the beginning of the line with the cursor over it.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably dupe, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337529/how-to-update-a-printed-message-in-terminal-without-reprinting-linux Also: ncurses

Comment: Well you didn't tell us what it is actually doing so how are we supposed to guess what is actually wrong?

Comment: @BaummitAugen sorry, I did look, but all questions I found were for C# :/ I will try the first answer. Though I'm pretty that was my first implementation (printf with carriage return)

Comment: @Jeff As always, if you have a problem with your existing code, please post a [mcve].

Comment: This is only going to ever print 0 or multiples of 256. Based on your explanation, I assume you never reach such a value, and only get zero. What I'm really not understanding is how this would relate to a progress bar in the first place.

Comment: @WilliamKappler This is the entire loop. Weight(int,int,int) is an int that's typically in the thousands/millions and soon billions if my partner can get his program working (in which case I'll have to make some vars long long ints). Does this extra bit of code help?

Comment: @WilliamKappler Ok, not a bar, but it should tell me how far along the program is in terms of reading the input file.

Comment: It's more descriptive, but I don't see anything obviously wrong. Perhaps you should break at the loop start and see what is actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(r / Weight(n+1, 4, d))` will always be 0 because `r` is an integer, `Weight(n+1, 4, d)` is integer too (i think) and `r` is always less than `Weight(n+1, 4, d)` (-> for loop).
Multiply with 100 before dividing if you want percentage output (0..100):

```
if (r%256==0) {fflush(stdout); cout << (r * 100 / Weight(n+1, 4, d)) << "\r";}
```

or cast to `float` or `double` if you want values printed from 0..1:

```
if (r%256==0) {fflush(stdout); cout << (static_cast<double>(r) / static_cast<double>(Weight(n+1, 4, d))) << "\r";}
```