# How do I remove text from the console in PHP?

Tags: php, windows, linux, command-line, php-5.3

My goal is to print an updating progress percentage to the console (in both Linux and Windows). Currently I just print out the percentage each 10%, but I would prefer that it updated itself every 1% without filling the screen with percentages.

Is it possible to remove text you have written to the console in PHP?

Comment: Alternatively use `print "17%\r";`. If you use carriage return `\r` instead of newline `\n`, the cursor will be placed at the beginning of the line, which allows the next output to overwrite it.

Comment: mario: Thanks! That answers a question I haven't asked yet :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo chr(8);
```

will print a backspace character.

Comment: Nice! This works in the windows CMD. Will this work in Linux though?

Answer (score 2):

very simple
Note the example below

```
$removeLine = function (int $count = 1) {
    foreach (range(1,$count) as $value){
        echo "\r\x1b[K"; // remove this line
        echo "\033[1A\033[K"; // cursor back
    }
};

echo "-----------------------------\n";
echo "---------  Start  -----------\n";
echo "-----------------------------\n";
sleep(2);
$removeLine(3);

echo 'hi';
sleep(2);
$removeLine();

echo 'how are you ?';
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`Zend_ProgressBar`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.progressbar.introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

PEAR's [Console_ProgressBar](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.console.console-progressbar.php) is useful for this sort of use case.

To clear the console entirely, you can use:

```
if($_SERVER['SHELL']) {
  print chr(27) . "[H" . chr(27) . "[2J";
}
```

which is quite a bit easier than keeping track of how many characters to backspace.