# How to erase characters printed in console

Tags: node.js

I've been searching how to do it in other languages and I've found that I have to use the special character \b to remove the last character. ([how-do-i-erase-printed-characters-in-a-console-applicationlinux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430713/how-do-i-erase-printed-characters-in-a-console-applicationlinux))

This doesn't work for node.js in multiple calls to console.log ();

If I write a single log:

```
console.log ("abc\bd");
```

I get the result: abd

But if I write:

```
console.log ("abc");
console.log ("\bd");
```

I get the result:

abc
d

My goal is to print a waiting message like:

Waiting
Waiting.
Waiting..
Waiting...

and again:

Waiting
Waiting.
etc

all in the same line.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

There are functions available for `process.stdout`:

```
var i = 0;  // dots counter
setInterval(function() {
  process.stdout.clearLine();  // clear current text
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0);  // move cursor to beginning of line
  i = (i + 1) % 4;
  var dots = new Array(i + 1).join(".");
  process.stdout.write("Waiting" + dots);  // write text
}, 300);
```

It is possible to provide arguments to `clearLine(direction, callback)`

```
/**
 * -1 - to the left from cursor
 *  0 - the entire line // default
 *  1 - to the right from cursor
 */
```

**Update** Dec 13, 2015: although the above code works, it is no longer documented as part of `process.stdin`. It has moved to [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)

Comment: I expect that under the hood the '\r' character is enabling this. This character returns the cursor to the beginning of the line without starting new line.

Comment: Not on windows though.

Comment: @pimvdb Where are these functions documented? They don't appear to be in the Node docs: http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on OSX, does anyone know if it should?

Comment: It's possible the API changed. This answer was written two years ago, and any JS developer should at least have some sort of idea how much has changed in the last two years. We've gone from a few compile-to-JS languages (most notably CoffeeScript) to transpiling the newest version coming out (that's nearing publishing), ES6. Two years ago, if I recall correctly, ES6 modules didn't even exist.

Comment: Can confirm `.cursorTo()` is still functional.

Comment: This does not work when the line had been split in the shell (i. e. was over 80 characters). In that case only the last row is wiped. Do you know of any way to wipe everyting until the last newline?

Comment: Hm, this works in Node 4.0 but it does not work in Node 1.12.1. I think (the version that ships with meteor). I think the `readline` library has this functionality though.

Answer (score 19):

Now you could use `readline` library and its [API](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_clearline_stream_dir) to do this stuff.

Comment: does not deserve a lib `require`

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way to overwrite the same line is

```
var dots = ...
process.stdout.write('Progress: '+dots+'\r');
```

the `\r` is the key. It will move the cursor back to the beginning of the line.

Comment: The only problem with '\r' is that it doesn't clear the current line. So if you write "abcdefg\r" the first time and "zyxw\r" the next time you'll end up with "zyxwefg".

Comment: Thats true, but in this case you should always be writing a longer line than the one before.

Comment: Not in the OP's case.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
process.stdout.write('\033c');
process.stdout.write('Your text here');
```

Comment: doesn't work in strict mode

Answer (score 1):

## Using a Carriage Return

The carriage return character places the cursor back at the beginning of the current line.

```
process.stdout.write("\r");
```

This solution worked for me — I only tested it with a single character.

Comment: Carriage Return is incorrect here as it erases the whole line. If you replace it with `\b` in your answer it will work. Also, make sure to update your example so that someone reading it can immediately understand your example (here I'm wondering: why not trying to erase a character to demonstrate it's working properly?)

Answer (score -3):

Try by moving the \r at the start of the string, this worked on Windows for me:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i+=1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(`\r ${i}`);
    }, i);
}
```

Comment: This won't work - `console.log` adds a `\n` to the end of your string. You need to use `process.stdout.write`