# Node.js console.log - Is it possible to update a line rather than create a new line?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My `node.js` application has a lot of console logs, which are important for me to see (it's quite a big app so runs for a long time and I need to know that things are still progressing) but I'm ending up with thousands of lines of console logs.

Is it somehow possible to do a `console.update` that erases/replaces a console line rather than creating a new line?

Comment: Why not write to a log file that you can monitor or search?

Comment: I can do that easily enough in PowerShell, but it's more that I have about 5,000 lines of console being written that could easily take up 10 lines (most of it is just calls that let me know that things are progressing, which is important as the app runs for about 20min and I need feedback on whether things are breaking/still running).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to erase characters printed in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600890/how-to-erase-characters-printed-in-console)

Answer (score 197):

Try playing with process.stdout methods instead on console:

```
process.stdout.write("Hello, World");
process.stdout.clearLine(0);
process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
process.stdout.write("\n"); // end the line
```

TypeScript: `clearLine()` takes -1, 0, or 1 as a direction parameter with the following meanings:

> -1: to the left from cursor.
> 0: the entire line.
> 1 - to the right from cursor

Comment: TypeError: process.stdout.clearLine is not a function. Can't be run in webstorm if anyone else encounters this.

Comment: @TrevorD my approach to this was to add a `webstorm=true` in Application parameters in webstorm node configuration and check for `process.argv.find(x => x.startsWith('webstorm=true')` using this answer

Comment: @Luiz Eduardo Would it not be simpler to just wrap in `if (process.stdout.clearLine) { process.stdout.clearLine() }` ?

Comment: Good catch! For some reason, I didn't even think of that. As I was building a little simple tool to run in the console, I didn't give it a thorough though, but I'll definitely change it, thanks!

Comment: I would do this:
`node -e "for(let i=1;i<=1000;i++){process.stdout.write('Hello, World'); if(i<10)process.stdout.clearLine(); process.stdout.cursorTo(0);}"` or `node -e "for(let i=1;i<=1000;i++){process.stdout.clearLine(); process.stdout.cursorTo(0); process.stdout.write('hello, world')}"`

Comment: @Trevor, I wrote a comment below regarding that error - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55893009/836723

Comment: This is what solved my problem when I got 'TypeError: process.stdout.clearLine is not a function': https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570694/3411285

Answer (score 98):

Following @michelek's answer, you can use a function somewhat like this:

```
function printProgress(progress){
    process.stdout.clearLine(0);
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
    process.stdout.write(progress + '%');
}
```

Comment: When using this with a for loop, it is flickering, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: to fix flicker, get rid of `process.stdout.clearLine()`

Comment: i realized adding this to a large loop increases the calculation time drasticallyyyy.
For example I am running 100mil random tries and assigning to variables. It should take 3 seconds. with this function. it takes like a minute

Comment: nevermind my above comment. I guess all console logs cost a lot. and Since I was trying to print a progress by percentage I had to write a function that only prints on certain intervals like 1% 2% etc

Answer (score 35):

Sure, you can do this using a module I helped create: [fknsrs/jetty](https://github.com/fknsrs/jetty)

Install via

```
npm install jetty
```

Here's a usage example

```
// Yeah, Jetty!
var Jetty = require("jetty");

// Create a new Jetty object. This is a through stream with some additional
// methods on it. Additionally, connect it to process.stdout
var jetty = new Jetty(process.stdout);

// Clear the screen
jetty.clear();

// write something
jetty.text("hello world");
jetty.moveTo([0,0]);
jetty.text("hello panda");
```

Jetty is not super useful when used on it's own. It is much more effective when you build some abstraction on top of it to make your jetty calls less verbose.

Comment: I downvoted this because of the restrictive license on this package.

Comment: It's a standard [BSD 3-clause licsense](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause). Pretty bad reason for a down-vote, imo.

Comment: @mmmeff, if you think a BSD 3-clause license is restrictive, I fear you'll die when you hear about GPL and AGPL licenses.

Answer (score 29):

Just use \r to terminate your line:

```
process.stdout.write('text\r');
```

Here's a simple example (wall clock):

```
setInterval(() => process.stdout.write(`clock: ${new Date()}\r`), 1000);
```

Comment: This works, but if the 'changed' line is shorter than the previous line, it will keep some of the old characters in the terminal.

Comment: This is awesome. Anyone know how this works?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah pretty simple: `\r` means carriage return. After `\r` the cursor goes to line start, so the previous output will be overriden by new.

Answer (score 16):

To write a partial line.

```js
process.stdout.write('text');
process.stdout.write('more');
process.stdout.write('\n'); // end the line
```

If the volume of output is the real issue then you'll probably to rethink your logging. You could use a logging system that allows selective runtime logging to narrow your output to what you need.

```js
// The sections we want to log and the minimum level
var LOG_LEVEL = 4;
var LOG_SECTIONS = ['section1', 'section2', 'section3'];

function logit(msg, section, level) {
  if (LOG_SECTIONS.includes(section) && LOG_LEVEL >= level) {
    console.log(section + ':' + msg);
  }
}

logit('message 1', 'section1', 4); // will log
logit('message 2', 'section2', 4); // will log
logit('message 3', 'section3', 2); // wont log, below log level
logit('message 4', 'section4', 4); // wont log, not in a log section
```

Answer (score 9):

We can use [log-update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-update)

```
const logUpdate = require('log-update');
logUpdate('this will be gone');
logUpdate('this will stay');
```

Answer (score 6):

if you see stdout exceptions like `TypeError: process.stdout.clearLine is not a function` in Debug Console window of Visual Studio Code (or Webstorm), run the app as external terminal application instead of internal console. The reason is that Debug Console window is not TTY (`process.stdout.isTTY` is false). Therefore update your launch configuration in `launch.json` with `"console": "externalTerminal"` option.

Answer (score 5):

Among others, the answer by @michelek does the trick. However, when you start using this, you may run into Exception trouble when output gets redirected to a file or you are in a debugger or running in a linux screen-session, etc. You may see messages such as `process.stdout.clearLine is not a function`.

Therefore, at least add a test to check that the output is a 'TTY' and is able to do such things as 'clearLine()' and 'cursorTo()':

```js
if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
   process.stdout.write("Hello, World");
   process.stdout.clearLine(0);
   process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
   process.stdout.write("\n"); // end the line
}
```