# Update more than just the last line of output

Tags: node.js, stdout

I know how I can update the last line of output ([answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309749/node-js-console-log-is-it-possible-to-update-a-line-rather-than-create-a-new-l)).

I've noticed though that some programs update more than just the last line.

Here is an example from yarn's output:
[image: yarn output]

All the `waiting...` lines have a "rotating dot" at the beginning of them, none of which is in the last line.

How can one achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ANSI Escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) to move the cursor...

Example : printing `"\033[3A"` will make the cursor move three lines up

If I have understood what you want... This should help:

```
var writeEscape = a => process.stdout.write("\033[" + a);
var moveUp = n => writeEscape(n +"A")
var moveDown = n => writeEscape(n + "B")
var moveRight = n => writeEscape(n +"C")
var moveLeft = n => writeEscape(n + "D")
var waitFor = n => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r,n))

writeEscape("25l"); // hide cursor use writeEscape("","25h") to show it again
process.stdout.write("waiting\n")
process.stdout.write("some other text");
moveUp(1)
moveLeft(15) // "some other text".length = 15

var printWaiting = async() => {
    writeEscape("K"); // erase the whole line

    process.stdout.write("waiting")

    await waitFor(1000)
    process.stdout.write(".")

    await waitFor(1000)
    process.stdout.write(".")

    await waitFor(1000)
    process.stdout.write(".")

    moveLeft(10) // "waiting".length = 7, "...".length = 3

    await waitFor(1000)
    printWaiting()
}
printWaiting();
```

I have used async/await functions... But setTimeout only will also work...