# How could I show the uptime in the console that continues to update as the time changes?

Tags: node.js

I am creating a Discord bot using Node and Discord.js and I want to show the uptime in the console but... I want it to continuously change as time changes.

I have tried and have succeeded in the past of making some loop using process.stdout.write but I can't remember how.

I have tried...

```
process.stdout.write(process.uptime());
process.stdout.clear();
```

and it didn't work.

I expect the uptime of the process to show up in the console as...

Uptime: 0D 0H 0M 1S

and as time changes is I want it to update that line and not make another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to initiate a loop and update the line periodically:

```
setInterval(() => {
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0); // Stay on the same line
  let uptime = Math.floor(process.uptime());
  process.stdout.write('Uptime: ' + uptime + 'S');
}, 1000)
```

I let you make the time conversion in minutes, hours and days for the display.

Credit for `cursorTo()` method: [michelek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561178/5156280)

Comment: Works perfectly thank you and [michelek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561178/5156280) so much +1. also no worries I know how to do the conversion.