# How to use setTimeout in JavaScript to print ellipsis on the same line at different times?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So this is my code so far:

```
let name = input.question("Please Provide a Name: ");

if (name === "Casper" || name === "casper"){
  console.log("Access Granted");
  function printMessage(){
    console.log(.);
  }
   setTimeout(printMessage, 1000);
} else {
      console.log("Access Denied");
}
```

What I want to do is print "..." after Access is Granted, but with each "." printing after a delay, and of course on the same line.

Thanks in advance to any help I get!

Comment: You can see this question if you're using node [Node.js console.log - Is it possible to update a line rather than create a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309749/node-js-console-log-is-it-possible-to-update-a-line-rather-than-create-a-new-l)

Comment: For a library see [log-update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-update) or, for full blown terminal ui see [blessed](https://github.com/chjj/blessed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) instead

```js
let 
    counter = 0,
    elipsisInterval = setInterval(() => {
        counter++;
        console.log(`Access Granted${".".repeat(counter)}`);
        if (counter === 3) {
            counter=0;
        }
    }, 1000)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This will print

```
Access Granted.
Access Granted..
Access Granted...
Access Granted.
Access Granted..
Access Granted...
```

Each second
Because console.log() defaults to end on a line break
Apparently if you're on NodeJS (so not on the frontend) you can use

```
process.stdout.write("Access Granted")
process.stdout.write(".")
```

and it will stay on the same line