# nodejs delete stdout line

Tags: node.js, logging, stdout

You can [delete individual characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600890/how-to-erase-characters-printed-in-console) using the `process.stdout` module, but how do you delete an entire line without having to print individual spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't find this documented, but ended up finding it by running `process.stdout.__proto__`. There's a `clearLine` function:

`process.stdout.clearLine()`