# How to make a "progress bar" using printf?

Tags: c, printf

Many command line tools implement text-based progress bar. Like rpm installing:

> installing ##############[45%]

the `#` grows with the percentage, while keeps itself in **a single line**. What I want is something similar: I need a progress indicator taking just one line, that is to say, when percentage grows, it got overwritten, instead of make a new line(`\n`).

I tried this:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main (){
       int i = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
           printf("\rIn progress %d", i/100);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
```

`\r` works to overwrite the single line. However, `\r` brings cursor to the beginning of line and `printf` brings cursor to the end, which result in a rapidly waving cursor. You guys can feel it by a little compiling. Can Anyone come up with alternatives to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a problem of the `stdout` stream being buffered. You have to flush it explicitly (implicit flushing occurs with a `\n`) using `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf()`:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine. Actually I bear little concept of buffered stream, could you present some explanation or further reference in detail?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how rpm did it, maybe you can write a similar function for your own purpose: [printHash](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/a7c3886b356c2f3e3e640069623d44d62beabb33/lib/rpminstall.c#L30-L77).

`rpm` use `\b` instead of `\r` to erase the output line character by character.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using

```
printf("\e[?25l");
```

may be able to help. This will hide the cursor. Honestly, I'm not sure if using /r or printf again will override that bit of code and show the cursor, but it's worth a shot. Also, the below code can be used to show the cursor again.

```
printf("\e[?25h");
```

Answer (score 0):

To use formatting on your terminal, check the [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving your some erroneous and non-portable code lines, I'd recommend you to read through the man pages for your system's [termcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) and [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo). It's a bit hard to follow at first, but it's a must-read if your about to start mucking with terminal-dependent code. The Wikipedia pages are a good place to start, but then do give the man pages on your system a read as well.

Also I just realized your question is most definitely a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430713/how-do-i-erase-printed-characters-in-a-console-applicationlinux) of a few other questions.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I'd thank everyone who directs me to some vital subjects that I'm not aware of.